# Can the name of a Schematron phase name be bound to a global variable or parameter?

Tags: xslt, schematron

I would like to alter a key parameter in a Schematron + XSLT project that affects the depth of validation, and the most convenient way would be to bind the name of the Schematron phase to a global variable (or an  within the Schematron file)

I have a workaround, where a Schematron  is tethered to a corresponding  that defines a particular , and that works, but it means that each phase has to change the variable of a unique parameter name, because it is not legal to include in a single file multiple s (or s) for the same parameter (variable).

```xml
   <phase id="terse">
      <active pattern="core-tests"/>
      <active pattern="terse-true"/>
   </phase>
   <phase id="verbose">
      <active pattern="core-tests"/>
      <active pattern="verbose-true"/>
   </phase>
   <pattern id="terse-true">
      <xsl:param name="validation-is-terse" select="true()"/>
   </pattern>
   <pattern id="verbose-true">
      <xsl:param name="validation-is-verbose" select="true()"/>
   </pattern>
```

I would prefer to write something like this:

```xml
   <xsl:param name="validation-depth" select="{$phase}"/>
   <phase id="terse">
      <active pattern="core-tests"/>
   </phase>
   <phase id="verbose">
      <active pattern="core-tests"/>
   </phase>
```

Comment: When is your variable varying and in which way? Is it just the depth or are in the variable the names of the neccessary elements? It would be really helpful to see your existing code...
Normally you can alter parameters through recursion.

Comment: In XSLT / Schematron, unlike other programming languages, global parameters and variables cannot be altered during processing. The key problem here is not so much the parameters and variables, but how to get the name of a Schematron phase to bind it to any variable whatsoever, aside from the forking technique in my current example (which works, but is not elegant, and feels like a hack).